# Python classes organizing issue

Tags: python, python-class

I have come across on an issue during organizing python classes recently.
I have such code:

```
class CategoryType(ABC):
    """Represents a generic category type."""
    ...


@dataclass
class WithSubCategoriesCategoryType(CategoryType):
    """Represents a common category type (DRINKS, BURGERS, etc.)"""

    sub_categories: list[SubCategory] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_sub_category(self, sub_category: SubCategory) -> None:
        self.sub_categories.append(sub_category)


@dataclass
class NoSubCategoriesCategoryType(CategoryType):
    """Represents a 'Combo', 'Lacky Pack' category type."""

    products: list[Product] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_product(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self.products.append(product)


@dataclass
class Category:
    """Represents a generic category."""

    category_name: CategoryName
    category_type: CategoryType
```

So as you can see, despite these classes there are SubCategory and Product ones. The SubCategory class also has the field **products** like NoSubCategoriesCategoryType:

```
@dataclass
class SubCategory:
    """Represents a generic sub-category."""

    sub_category_name: SubCategoryName
    products: list[Product] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_product(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self.products.append(product)
```

The question is that's the right way dealing with organizing classes like that or there's a better solution? Because I'm worried about duplicating code like **products** field and **add_product** function in NoSubCategoriesCategoryType and SubCategory itself.

Comment: You question is not clear, can you explain a bit more? And what you mean by "organizing classes" ?

Comment: If we talk about clear questions: there is any way to avoid duplication like described above? If it's so then "organizing classes" means to redo this set-up of classes due to inheritance, for example or any other techniques. I hope it's more clarifying.

Comment: Are you referring `add_sub_category` and `add_product` as duplicates ?

Comment: Nope. I mean `add_product` in `SubCategory` and `add_product` in `NoSubCategoriesCategoryType`. Are they could be considered as duplicates of code?

Comment: But `SubCategory` is not inheriting `CategoryType`.

Comment: So, that's completely ok if `SubCategory` must not be inherited from `CategoryType`?